# xpath returns only one result

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml document looks like:

```
<xmlList>  

  <Phone> 
     <Prefix>04</Prefix>
  </Phone>  

  <Phone> 
     <Prefix>04</Prefix>
  </Phone> 

  <Phone> 
     <Prefix>03</Prefix>
  </Phone>   

</xmlList>
```

I would like to retrieve the `Prefix` node content onlt in case it is `04`.

```
String xml = "<xmlList><Phone><Prefix>04</Prefix></Phone><Phone><Prefix>04</Prefix></Phone><Phone><Prefix>03</Prefix></Phone></xmlList>";

XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));  

 // only one string is returned
String prefix = xpath.evaluate("/xmlList/Phone/Prefix", source);
```

Only one string is retrieved from `xpath.evaluate`.
I would like to get a list with all of the 04 occurences in given XML.

Possible?

Comment: Most likely you have to iterate over the result of `xpath.evaluate()` using a for loop, because it returns a list of nodes.

Comment: Is this java or javaScript?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.InputSource%29, that overload of the `evaluate` method evaluates the XPath and returns the result as string. As with XPath 1.0 the string value of a set of nodes is the string value of the first node in the node set, you get a string with the contents of the first selected node.

So you will need to use a different overload where you can specify the result type as NODESET and then you can iterate over the returned NodeList to collect the values.

Or consider to switch to an XPath 2.0 or 3.0 or XQuery 1.0 or 3.0 implementation like Saxon 9 where there are then APIs to return a sequence of strings for e.g. `/xmlList/Phone/Prefix/string()`. You will need to use a different API however than the JAXP XPath API which is centered around XPath 1.0.